# How to set default datefield and overwrite it as well as set default default datetimefield and overwrite it, all in the same models.py

Tags: python, django, datefield

Two of my models have datefield and datetimefield. They exist in the same models.py file and I would like to set them to be default upon adding to the database / into existence. More importantly, I would also like to overwrite these fields for generating models to test them.

After some research, I started to use pytz and django.utils timezone. The problem I run into are runtime errors when I try to overwrite them using python's built in datetime (using things like timedelta etc). So I tried converting pytz.utc.localize(), but it complained that the datetime objects I fed it was not naive, but then when I go back to my original version, it still threw the Runtime error. I've found many ways to get over this, mainly using things like `date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)` which requires `import datetime`, but the problem here is that I also want to use DateTimeField and now just DateField. So I would use `date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=date.today)`, but this requires `from datetime import date`. The imports conflict and the entire thing is messing with me

```
class SomeTime(models.Model):
    moment = models.DateTimeField(default=???, editable=True, blank=True)

class SomeDay(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=???, editable=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to go

```
m = SomeTime()

m.moment = #some datetime that I set, It should not throw a runtime error

m.save()

d = SomeDay()

d.date = #some date that I set, It should not throw a runtime error

d.save()
```

As well as simply create these objects, SomeTime must save the current datetime to moment, and SomeDay must save the current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're finding problems where there aren't any. If you need to import both datetime and date, then just do so. Or even better, import the datetime module and access both classes within it.

```
import datetime


class SomeTime(models.Model):
    moment = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=True, blank=True)

class SomeDay(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, editable=True, blank=True)
```

Or if you prefer, do `from datetime.import datetime, date` then `default=datetime.now` and `default=date.today`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting runtime errors when I set the field to some other date though. But the runtime error doesn't seem to affect anything else and still runs fine

Answer (score 0):

you need to import datetime first.

```
import datetime
```

then from your code.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

m = SomeTime()

m.moment = now

m.save()

d = SomeDay()

d.date = now.date()

d.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

For models.DateTimeField use:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

# set default date
default_date = parse_datetime('2000-01-01T00:00:00')

class SomeTime(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_date)
```

You can update this field with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

filtered_sometime.update(date = now)
# with usage of time delta
filtered_sometime.update(date = now() + relativedelta(months=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Runtime warning, you can go to your settings.py and comment out "USE_TZ = True". This is just a temporary solution, we would like to find a way to avoid runtime errors altogether while looking at international use